# Make half outline in the svg

Tags: svg

I have an SVG which looks like the image below:

[image]

Code for SVG is below:

```html
   <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="75"
      height="61"
      viewBox="0 0 75 61"
    >
      <path
        d="M75.2 0v61H0V0c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1h-.1z"
        fill="red"
      />
    </svg>
```

I want to have an outline of black at only the half circular part of the svg, I am new to svg, so I am not able to do it. Please help.

**NOTE**: ignore the black outline at the top and bottom, that is not the part of svg, it comes because I have taken screenshot of my application. Only the red part is svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you may use a different path whose's d attribute is a part of the previous path d attribute.

This is the d attribute you have:

```
d="M75.2 0v61H0V0
   c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33
   c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1
   h-.1z"
```

For the new d attribute you remove `M75.2 0v61H0V0`. This is drawing part of the lines and ends in the point 0,0. You will use this point as a starting point: `M0,0` Next you are using the bézier curves `c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33 c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1` without the part that is closing the path.

This new path have `fill="none"` and the stroke of the color and width you like.

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="75"
  height="61"
  viewBox="0 0 75 61"
>
  <path
    d="M75.2 0v61H0V0
       c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33
       c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1
       h-.1z"
    fill="red"
  />
  
  <path
    d="M0,0
    c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33
    c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could have used the exact same path, but used s dash pattern to stroke the correct section.

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="75"
  height="61"
  viewBox="0 0 75 61"
>
  <path
    d="M75.2 0v61H0V0c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1h-.1z"
    fill="red"
  />
  <path
    d="M75.2 0v61H0V0c4.1 0 7.4 3.1 7.9 7.1C10 21.7 22.5 33 37.7 33c15.2 0 27.7-11.3 29.7-25.9.5-4 3.9-7.1 7.9-7.1h-.1z"
    fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"
    stroke-dasharray="0 197 109 100"
  />
</svg>
```